# Xamarin.Forms.UWP Lottie animation not showing

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, lottie

I am having problems with getting Lottie animations to work in my xamarin.forms.uwp project.

I downloaded the sources and got the sample ([partly](https://github.com/Baseflow/LottieXamarin/issues/312)) working.
I tried to reproduce this working scenario in a fresh Xamarin.Forms project, but no success on the UWP side.
I am using

- Visual Studio 16.8.3
- Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0.1821
- Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie (4.0.8)

I played "spot the differences" between the working sample and my fresh project, but so far, I haven't found what the sample project does differently.

To my knowledge I need to take the following steps:

- add a reference to the nuget package Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie (4.0.8) to both the Shared Project and the UWP project
- add a lottie json file to the Assets dir of the UWP project and mark it with Build action "Content". I'm using the same lottie.json file as in the sample just to be sure.
- add an animation view to the page like the following:

```
    <forms:AnimationView             
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                AutoPlay="True"
                RepeatMode="Infinite"
                Animation="LottieLogo1.json"
                AnimationSource="AssetOrBundle"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

In my sample app I can see the red background color but not the animation. This might have something to do with the non working [behaviour](https://github.com/Baseflow/LottieXamarin/issues/313) on the start page

Is there some initialization logic for UWP that I am missing?

Comment: Try to move the `.json` files from the Assets folder to the project folder. Also try to reference your animation on code behind and launch `Play()` method to check if the animation runs. Remove the `AnimationSource` property

Comment: @FabriBertani I am trying to copy the setup of the working version in the samples dir of the sources, all three of your suggestions should not be necessary according to the working sample. I still tried them but to no effect unfortunately.

Comment: using the latest versions of lottie, xamarin forms, targetting android 10.0 and it is not working not even an error, I start to believe that lottie is broken. not even a decent  official documentation for troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm targeting android 10 and have it working there, this topic is about xamarin.forms.uwp